# ASP.NET Identity 2 - injecting ISecureDataFormat<>

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, unity-interception

I'm having same issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962597/structuremap-web-api-2-account-controller-and-individual-accounts) with no answer, just using Unity.

I'm trying to register `ISecureDataFormat<>` in the lastest VS2013 (update 2) SPA/Web Api template.

I've tried

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ISecureDataFormat<>), typeof(SecureDataFormat<>));
container.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();
container.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketDataFormat>();
```

It "works" but not really because then it complains about the next depenedency in that tree, IDataSerializer... and then the next IDataProtector, for which I found no implementation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved the following error in SimpleInjector with the following mappings

```
container.Register<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>, TicketSerializer>();
container.Register<IDataProtector>(() => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
```

To figure out what serializer was used I noticed that the ISecureDataFormat generic parameter in the AccountsController was a AuthenticationTicket type. In checking the IDataSerializer namespace the TicketSerializer implements IDataSerializer.

To figure out IDataProtector I again looked in the IDataProtector namespace and found the implementation of the IDataProtectionProvider.