# Injecting ISecureDataFormat in Web API 2 AccountController using Autofac

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP.NET Identity 2.2 in a Web API 2 project but I am unsure how to wire up the `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` dependency of the `AccountController` using *Autofac*.

I tried this:

```
builder.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>()
       .As<TicketDataFo‌​rmat>();
```

and getting error:

> The type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.ISecureDataFormat`1[Microsoft.Owin.Security.Authenticat‌​ionTicket]' is not assignable to service 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.TicketDataFormat'

None of the questions I came across seem to work using the latest stable release of ASP.NET Identity.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share with us what did you try and what were the error messages ?

Comment: I tried this: `builder.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>().As<TicketDataFormat>();` and getting error: The type 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.ISecureDataFormat`1[Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket]' is not assignable to service 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.TicketDataFormat'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do the oposite. With *Autofac* you register a type as a Service.

```
builder.RegisterType<TicketDataFo‌​rmat>()
       .As<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>();
```

and based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375790/asp-net-identity-2-injecting-isecuredataformat), it seems that you also need to register a `IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>` and a `IDataProtector` implementation.

```
builder.RegisterType<TicketSerializer>()
       .As<IDataSerializer<AuthenticationTicket>>();
builder.Register(c => new DpapiDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.NET Identity"))
       .As<IDataProtector>();
```